# How to draw colorful rotating flower in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, p5.js

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  petals();
  noStroke(); //the center of flower = white circle
  fill(255);
  ellipse(200, 200, 130, 130);

  function petals() { //flower leaves -> I wanna fill them with rainbow colors each in shortly
    push()
      translate(200, 200);
      rotate(radians(90));
      noStroke();
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
    pop()

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

How can I color those leaves?

I added `fill('red')`, `fill('blue')` in front of each ellipse and somehow only one color dominates all of the petals.

Plus, I want it to rotate at a constant speed.

Comment: Can you show your code with `fill` before each call? This should work. Rotating is a separate question--best to focus on one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill seems to work fine.  (and added a loop to be more concise)...

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  petals();
  noStroke(); //the center of flower = white circle
  fill(255);
  ellipse(200, 200, 130, 130);

  function petals() { //flower leaves -> I wanna fill them with rainbow colors each in shortly
    push()
    translate(200, 200);
    noStroke();
    const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'];
    for (let i=0; i<8; i++) {
      let color = colors[i%4];
      fill(color)
      ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
    }
    pop()

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow Thank you so much for your help!! TT Sorry but Can I ask you one more question..?? 
I wanna make a rotating flower which responds the loudness of real-time microphone..! Here is my new question link...!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72470552/how-to-make-a-rotating-flower-which-only-responds-to-the-mic

Comment: @rose - supplied an answer as well as I could. The convention on the site is, when you find an answer worthwhile, you vote it up with the arrow on the upper left, and if you determine that it answers the question, you mark it as correct with the little checkbox on the upper left.

Comment: Thanks! it was my first time of using this page :) I did it! i hope I did right..!

Comment: :-) well done.  on the other question, though, you marked it right a little early if you don't think its right.

Comment: hello,,,! sorry but could u help me with this question...?? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727637/i-coded-a-coloring-brush-but-it-is-not-working-in-p5js