# how to control flower animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, real-time, flower

```
let angle = 0
let mic; 
let fft;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  mic = new p5.AudioIn(); //AUDIO SETTING
  mic.start();
  
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);
}


function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  petals();
  noStroke(); 
  fill(255);
  ellipse(200, 200, 100, 100); // the center of flower 
  
  function petals() { 
    push()
    translate(200, 200); // flower leaves
     rotate(angle);
    noStroke();
    const colors = ['magenta','red', 'orange','#7fff00','#0f0','#0ff','blue','#bf49ff'];
    let waveform = fft.waveform();
    
    for (let i=0; i<8; i++) {
      let y = 100 -  waveform[i]*100;   //i want those flower leaves to rotate responds to mic
      let color = colors[i];
      fill(color)
      ellipse(100, 0, 200, 60)
      rotate(radians(45));
     angle = angle +0.003
    }
    pop()

  }
}
```

//I want my leaves to rotate in response to the loudness of real-time sound input from the microphone. I think I should use pff but... it doesn't work. Please help me TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a design with a fake calculation transforming FFT output to a rotational rate. (real mic input won't run in snippets)

The point is to: (1) demonstrate how to rotate the drawing, and (b) show how untangle the FFT math and the graphics.

**EDIT**

I tried the p5 sound library for the first time. Some things to note: (1) it won't work in stack overflow snippets, since the snippet can't access the client mic. (2) remember to import the p5 sound add-on, shown in the html below, (3) if you just want total amplitude, there's no need for FFT, just get the mic level from the p5 mic.  (4) I made up a function that works ok on my local machine, clipping the low and high amplitudes (though 1.0 is probably the max output by default).

```js
let mic;
let rotation = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  userStartAudio();
}

function rotationalRateForMicLevel(micLevel) {
  // in my experiment, low mic levels are ~0.01, high levels ~1.0;
  micLevel = Math.min(1.0, Math.max(0.5, micLevel));
  return radians(15) * micLevel
}

function petals() { //flower leaves -> I wanna fill them with rainbow colors each in shortly
  push()
  translate(200, 200);

  const micLevel = mic.getLevel();
  const rotationalRate = rotationalRateForMicLevel(micLevel)
  rotation += rotationalRate;
  rotate(rotation);
  
  noStroke();
  const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let color = colors[i % 4];
    fill(color)
    ellipse(100, 0, 250, 60)
    rotate(radians(45));
  }
  pop()
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  petals();
  noStroke(); //the center of flower = white circle
  fill(255);
  ellipse(200, 200, 130, 130);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But i want the animation which rotate depends on the loudness of microphone...! when there is no sound, it should stop and if there is sound, it should rotate hard...! but this code is just rotating.... TT

Comment: I understand.  I'll try to improve the answer later tonight, but in the meantime, you should edit the question to demonstrate how the FFT code will produce an array of 8 real numbered values.

Comment: oh... i see..! all i want is creating a rotating animation which only responds to the loudness of real-time sound input from the microphone. Sorry Actually I'm learning what the FFT is ...TT so I just referred to the references... i don't know how to change my question..!TT

Comment: @rose, I edited to demo a setup that works on my dev machine.  See the notes in the **Edit** section